# Get files of plist type

Tags: macos, cocoa, search, plist

I'm writing an OS X application for my personal use where I want to get and subsequently search all files of type plist. I am struggling with the first task. Could you point me in the right direction or provide an online tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to clarify. I don't want a global search, but rather for a given directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *searchDirectory = ...;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: searchDirectory 
                                                                     error: NULL];
[files enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *fileName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"plist"]) {
        NSString *filePath = [searchDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
        // Do something with the plist file
    }
}];
```

Comment: Don't check the path extension, check the UTI. `-[NSWorkspace typeOfFile:error:]` followed by `-type:conformsToType:` with "com.apple.property-list" as the type.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *folder = <# your folder #>;
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folder error:&error];
if (error) {
    <# deal with error #>
} else {
    NSString *path;
    for (NSString *entry in contents) {
        if ([entry hasSuffix:@"plist"]) {
            path = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:entry];
            <# do something with file at path #>
        }
    }
}
```

Also, check related methods in **Discovering Directory Contents** section in `NSFileManager` class reference.

Comment: It's still better to check the file extension explicitly because `hasSuffix:` will return `true` for a file named "someplist".

Comment: Which is awesome if it happens to be a plist file.